# Instagram API - user_recent_media broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I used to be able to return all of the users photos in my Rails app with

```
client = Instagram.client access_token: session[:access_token]
@photos = client.user_recent_media(count: -1)
```

but now @photos returns an empty array. Has this changed? Is there another way to return all of a user's photos?

Answer (score 0):

`count: -1` returns empty, instead use a large enough number and it works.

Comment: Including an explanation as to why this works would be beneficial not only to the asker but to future people who stumble across this post attempting to solve the same problem.

Comment: @Josh The [Documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent) gives no detailed explanation for the `count` parameter. I had tested -1 by guessing it might work but it did not so I used a large number and got the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I 've tried this.
In single call Instagram has restricted to get 20 media.

```
count: -1
```

worked earlier but not now when Instagram Api has changed a lot.
for now `count: -1` will return 20-1 =19 pics and placing `count: 15` will return 15 pics.

**Note:** With `count: 25` i.e greater than 20 will return 20 pics as per Instagram restrictions